# How do you omit a mule configuration from being included in the mule-deploy automatically in Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to define two mule-configuration files for global endpoints and connector definitions for production and testing purposes.  How do I setup my project such that the test configuration file is not automatically included in the mule-deploy.properties file automatically and that the duplicate names used for these endpoints/connectors or bean definitions do not collide and thus raising errors/warnings.

I want to create functional test cases that include the test configurations for the endpoints/connectors/beans, and not the production configurations.  This part I can do.  What I can't do is keep Anypoint Studio from also including these test configurations in the production build and deployment.

Comment: Are you deploying to the Anypoint Platform or an on-premise MMC?

Comment: on-premise.  thanks.

Comment: This Mulesoft documentation  may be of help.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-side-by-side-configuration-files